# CSS create two columns when window is too short

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have a page with an image with text below it, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e3vWe/1/
I've set

```
img {
width:80%;
max-width:900px;
display:block;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
}
```

The problem is, on smaller screens, the bottom of the image is cut off, and text below it requires scrolling to access. Is there a way (with separate stylesheets I assume) to make the text appear to the left of the image while keeping the entire page centered when the window has a height below, say, 600px? Also, for mobile users, revert to a mobile stylesheet when the window has a height of below 400px. Thanks.

Comment: ever heard of media queries??? => http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile

Answer (score 0):

Try this for all images and try media query for different style on different screen size.

```
img { max-width: 100% !important; }
```